# Pass class (not instance) to function, so that static methods still work, without redeclaring class as interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to pass a class (the class itself, not an instance of it) as an argument to a function, so that the function can 1) call static methods on the class and 2) instantiate the class.

I have gotten it to work, but the only way I could was to redeclare the whole class structure as an interfacce, so I am effectively declaring the class twice - once in the `class {}` declaration and again as the argument type for the function.

Is there a way to avoid doing this, so that I can reuse the class definition without having a duplicate type?

Here is working code that demonstrates the issue:

```
class Base {
    static id() { return { name: 'example', code: 'none' }; }
    static other1() { return 'example1'; }
    static other2() { return 'example2'; }
    constructor(a: number, b: number) { }
}

class A extends Base {
    static id() { return { ...super.id(), code: 'class-a' }; }
    static other1() { return 'example1A'; }
    constructor(a: number, b: number) { super(a, b + 1); }
}

class B extends Base {
    static id() { return { ...super.id(), code: 'class-b' }; }
    static other2() { return 'example2B'; }
    constructor(a: number, b: number) { super(a, b + 2); }
}

// I have to re-declare all the static functions here.  How can I replace
// this type with one that does it automatically from class `Base`?
interface BaseClassAsParameter<T> {
    new(...args: any): T;
    id: () => any;
    other1: () => any;
    other2: () => any;
    // If I add another static function to Base, I have to add it here too.
}

function testClass<T extends Base>(C: BaseClassAsParameter<T>): T {
    const { name, code } = C.id();
    const other1 = C.other1();
    const other2 = C.other2();

    console.log(`Test ${name} code ${code}: ${other1} ${other2}`);

    const x = new C(100, 200);
    // do something with x
    return x;
}

testClass(A); // should print "Test example code class-a: example1A example2"
testClass(B); // should print "Test example code class-b: example1 example2B"
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqeoqm) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz: Oh wow I can't believe it was that simple!  Yes that does answer the question.  If your writeup could also include a return type that would be most helpful (I've updated the question to show a return type in the function signature).  I tried using `InstanceType<T>` but it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: That requires a different approach; does [this one](https://tsplay.dev/NB4dpW) work for you?  Let me know.

Comment: That one works too!  I realised I should have included parameters in the class constructors so that a simple `new () => T` isn't enough, so hopefully that's a simple fix (your first proposed solution carried across the constructor parameters without issue) - I've updated the sample code to include constructor functions and parameters to `new()`.  When you do write your answer, it would be good to include both the solutions you have proposed so far, as I have learned from them both!  Thanks so much for this it's really helpful.

Comment: classes are basically a meme in javascript. the benefits of [modules](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_modules.html) vastly outweigh class-based approach.

Comment: @Mulan: Modules and classes serve quite different purposes, and in my case I am using both. My use case is that I need to communicate with a hundred or so different models of electrical meter, so having a single base class with functions like "read energy use" and "reset energy counters" means I can have descendent classes that implement those functions using whatever custom protocol a device requires, yet the code processing the data doesn't need to know anything device-specific. I have each child class in its own module but I am not sure what benefit you would get from avoiding classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is just make your function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `C` parameter, [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `typeof Base`:

```
function testClass<T extends typeof Base>(C: T) {
    const { name, code } = C.id();
    const other1 = C.other1();
    const other2 = C.other2();

    console.log(`Test ${name} code ${code}: ${other1} ${other2}`);

    const x = new C(100, 200) as InstanceType<T>;
    return x;
}

testClass(A); // A
testClass(B); // B
```

This works because the value `Base` has all the static methods you care about, and also has a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that takes two numbers and produces an instance of `Base`.  This will end up requiring that anything you pass to `testClass()` also has the same functionality.  Note that not every possible subclass of `Base` will work this way:

```
class Nope extends Base {
    constructor(x: string) { super(x.length, 2) }
}
testClass(Nope); // error!
// -----> ~~~~
//  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

That fails because the value `Nope` does not accept two numbers in its construct signature.

---

Anyway, that works.  The only possible issue is that the compiler prematurely widens the type of `new C(100, 200)` to the specific `Base` type instead of keeping it generic.  The right type is [`InstanceType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype), but that's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and the compiler is unable to verify that a value is assignable to a generic conditional type.  This is a current limitation of TypeScript.  (There are a bunch of relevant GitHub issues; for example, [microsoft/TypeScript#44049](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44049) is about the analogous problem with [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype).)

It's easy enough to just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) as above via `new C(100, 200) as InstanceType<T>` and move on.  This prevents a compiler error but only because you're telling the compiler that you know `new C(100, 200)` is indeed of type `InstanceType<T>`.  The compiler isn't verifying that and therefore won't catch you if you happen to be wrong about it.

---

If you want to have a little more type safety from the compiler you could go ahead and define a `BaseClassAsParameter<T>` utility type from `Base` as asked in the question.  Like this:

```
type BaseClassAsParameter<T extends Base> =
    (new (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Base>) => T) &
    typeof Base
```

Here we are manually providing a more specific construct signature where the instance type of `BaseClassAsParameter<T>` is `T`, but still pulling the constructor arguments from `Base` using [the `ConstructorParameters<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype).  By [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the call signature with `typeof Base`, I've made a type that technically has *two* call signatures; first is the specific one returning `T` instances, and the second is the original one returning `Base` instances.  When we call the construct signature, the compiler will use the same rules as with [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) and resolve with the first matching signature... so by putting the specific one first we should get that one.

Let's test it out:

```
function testClass<T extends Base>(C: BaseClassAsParameter<T>) {
    const { name, code } = C.id();
    const other1 = C.other1();
    const other2 = C.other2();

    console.log(`Test ${name} code ${code}: ${other1} ${other2}`);

    const x = new C(100, 200);
    return x;
}

testClass(A); // A
testClass(B); // B
```

Looks good.  Now the compiler automatically understands that `new C(100, 200)` produces a value of type `T`, and still knows about the static methods on `C`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.9.4#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-kwUvdDgCAAkjXoNbUG6-ah3cGK1XcPdnKIP64JqqQOvgzr7FQbTqgA9DB7TnGBEHwFQSCwfBSDbh8jIIAAcooKyej03oDEMrbVmKvxUKIggZMQ7A9gq0LUV2PQ9pY150O8wGIcO4GMlQ+ErOhnQMAwuQAITnHBODvoRQiAjUJzEIg6hxvsxA9twJTSPaii+vJdEMUIcygJqk66vq6Buke+nDIhH5BoMyGwG0sAAArQAwCbdAw7pEbiTmoMGabkVQx4IFQCxzF5PawIIjqxpk4oMJ53l8L5sAuvgH4BkFwZ0KmIWRggABk5E5f6gakVhuCWtaJB2khroel0xF4oMobhkFLluWlPnWF+UY7nmsbxnwSboNO6aZiSQG-vmZh1jYDalsttDzVWi1NqtTYbbVC3pB2qBdr2A5DiO46TtO85jhg87aIuGDLndTYbluYAjW2Y0HumEWOmel7Xrem2pDJFD6bAigZRY9E9ggR7EJY+7kf+nCAecIG4M1kHQfoMltLxToCWh+MYQdCg4UJ6BtYFpGmr+301slVE0RcDBw0x1gsdIDEcaqXGY0T-GQdTInWOJDBSZWMkIHJ6AKeCDDKap5gIBpWnQDp6A5AZCtGT2JlmduQA)